# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on fgets in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'm trying to read in a file line-by-line, but when my function is called, it crashes at the while (fgets line with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I've added the text file to the Xcode project.

This is the function in question:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayadd(NSString *date){
    static const char filename[] = "someText.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
    NSString *tmpline;
    NSArray *chunks;
    NSMutableArray *listtoAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    char line [ 512 ];
    int a=0;
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ){
        tmpline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", line];
       chunks = [tmpline componentsSeparatedByString: @" - "];

        if ((a>0 && a<8) || [chunks objectAtIndex: 0] == date){
            [listtoAdd addObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:1]];
            a=a+1;
            if (a==8){
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return listtoAdd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fgets` itself looks okay, but I notice you're not checking the return value from `fopen`, which may mean that `file` is set to `NULL`.

It's possible that the location where you've put your file is *not* where the environment is running your code from.